# How I can get products using multiple skus?

Tags: magento2.4, products

In my custom block I loaded the `ProductRepository`:

```
namespace \Pcmagas\FirstModule\Block\MyList;

class MyList extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    private ProductRepository $productRepository;
   
    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        ProductRepository $productRepository,
        array $data = []
    ){
        $this->productRepository=$productRepository;
    }

    public function getRelatedProducts()
    {
        /**
         * @var String[]
         */
        $skus = ['24-MB01','24-MB04','24-UG01'];
        return $this->productRepository->get($skus);
    }
}
```

But this method seem that does not return any product at my phtml:

```
<?php
    /**
     * @var $block Pcmagas\FirstModule\Block\MyList
     */
?>
<?=json_encode($block->getRelatedProducts(),JSON_PRETTY_PRINT&JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);?>
```

But I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository::getProductFromLocalCache(): Argument #1 ($sku) must be of type string, array given, called in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ProductRepository.php on line 286 and defined in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ProductRepository.php:818

...
```

But If I try to use the following:

```
        return $this->productRepository->get('24-MB01,24-MB04,24-UG01');
```

I get:

```
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException): The product that was requested doesn't exist. Verify the product and try again.
```

If I try this:

```
        return $this->productRepository->addFieldToFilter('sku',$skus);
```

I get the error:

```
Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository\Interceptor::addFieldToFilter() in /Pcmagas\FirstModule\Block\MyList.php:51
```

Is there a way to search using multiple skus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `get` method in the `Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository` class is used to retrieve a single product.

To retrieve multiple products, you need to use the `getList` method. The implementation should looks the following:

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);
namespace Pcmagas\FirstModule\Block\MyList;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class MyList extends Template
{
    private ProductRepository $productRepository;

    private SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder;

    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        ProductRepository $productRepository,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
    }

    public function getRelatedProducts()
    {
        $skuList = ['24-MB01','24-MB04','24-UG01'];
        $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter('sku', $skuList, 'in')->create();

        return $this->productRepository->getList($searchCriteria)->getItems();
    }
}
```

In addition, when declaring namespace, adding a backslash at the beginning is valid (`namespace \Pcmagas\FirstModule\Block\MyList`), you may have an error with this.

Answer (score 1):

There are **Multiple Ways** to get products using **multiple skus** in Magento2.

Some Repository Basics

- To get a **Single product** from a repository use **get**
- To get a **list of products** from a repository use **getList**
- To **filter any repository** use **SearchCriteriaBuilder**
- To **add a filter** use **FilterBuilder**
- To **group filters** use **FilterGroupBuilder**

In your case, you can use simple product collection to filter a list of products based on the provided skus.

```
use \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection; 

//Inject in your constructor 

/* @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection  */
$productResourceCollection

$skus = ['24-MB01','24-MB04','24-UG01'];
$_productCollection = $this->productResourceCollection
                        ->addAttributeToSelect(['sku','status','name']) // you can just use * for all attributes
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('sku',['in' => $skus]) // just use in condition to filter the collection 
                        ->load(); 

return $_productCollection
```

Or you can replace your code with this to filter the product repository

```
use \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
use \Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder;
use \Magento\Framework\Api\Search\FilterGroupBuilder;

//Inject the classes above in the constructor

/* @var \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder */

/* @var \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $filterBuilder */

/* @var \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $filterGroupBuilder */

// add this in your method  
$skus = ['24-MB01','24-MB04','24-UG01'];
$skusFilter = $this->filterBuilder
    ->setField(\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface::SKU)
    ->setConditionType('in')
    ->setValue($skus)
    ->create();
$filterGroupSkusList = $this->filterGroupBuilder->addFilter($skusFilter)->create();
$this->searchCriteriaBuilder->setFilterGroups([$filterGroupSkusList]);
$this->searchCriteriaBuilder->setPageSize(10);
$searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->create();

$productsList = $this->productRepository->getList($searchCriteria);

if ($productsList->getTotalCount() > 0)  {
    $_products = $productsList->getItems();
    return $_products;
}
```